# Consuming metadata from Informatica Data Catalog into AWS S3 or database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, informatica

I am working on data solution where need to process some metadata using AWS services either using EMR or Glue. The source of metadata is `Informatica Data Catalog`, which is owned by different organization. I have never worked in Informatica.

I am looking for the best approach how to extract metadata from `Informatica Data Catalog`. The approaches comes to my mind are -

1. `Informatica Data Catalog` puts the data into some database and give us the connection access.
2. `Informatica Data Catalog` writes the data as files and put into some storage from where we can access the data and store into S3 buckets.
3. Does `Informatica Data Catalog` provide/expose any REST API to be called to extract data from it?

Out of the above, which approach is preferable? Also, let me know if there is any other approach to achieve the same as this is my first data engineering project.

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate a bit more on your source? Informatica provides quite a few tools. Mainly ETL - so tools to process data, not store them. And here's my confusion: what data are you going to process, as the tool itself rather does not serve data. Unless you want to consume some metadata.

Comment: If your source targets are AWS DB or AWS files, I guess option 1 will be fast and better. Informatica provide lots of connectors, ODBC to connect to DB.

Comment: @Maciejg - I have updated the post, need to consume metadata from Informatica data catalog